# jquery how to filter unchecked checkboxes from a form

Tags: jquery, filter

In my page, i do have no.of checkboxes in the form. in that i am making checked some of them, i need to filter rest of the checkboxes and need to add separet event on those. i do like this:

```
var userLocales =   $('input[type="checkbox"]', "form").filter(function(){ 
                return $(this).val() === value["name"]
            }).prop("checked",true);

            $(userLocales).click(function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("red");
            })

            $('input:checkbox:not("checked")', "form").not(userLocales).click(function(){
                $(this).parent().addClass("green"); //this is not working.. it works even for not selected elements..
            })
```

But not working.. any correct way to get this done pelase..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `:checked` in the selector.

Try:

```
$('input:checkbox:not(":checked")', "form")
```

instead of

```
$('input:checkbox:not("checked")', "form")
```

Comment: can you please see my code, i using this already. but my intension is it should not happend anyway on my "userLocales" - elements

Comment: Could you replicate it in a fiddle. Problem is your code has many factors which is still not clear. A fiddle would help!

Answer (score 15):

Given that you know how to get the checkboxes in the first place, consider:

```
checkboxes$.filter(':checked')....
```

or:

```
checkboxes$.filter(':not(:checked)')....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input:checkbox:not(":checked")', "form").on('click',function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass("green");
});
```

Comment: @3gwebtrain Updated check the above one I've made changes in it.

Comment: I am pushing the value to array, when unchecked click, it pushed 6 times (count of checked element ) why..?